# combine data from in different sheets

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

I have Branch codes and zip codes mapped in 1 sheet. In another sheet I have branch codes and zone mapped . I need to combine all three in a single sheet without changing the mapping. Is there a way to do this in excel?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you need to use "[vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1)" to return zones to your branch codes and zip codes file.

```
=vlookup(reference cell, look up range, column to return, true/false exact match)
```

So, say, Book1 is Branch Codes in A and Zip Codes in B and then Book2 is Branch Codes in A and Zones in B, in file A you'd want (presuming data starts at row 2 with header in 1):

```
=vlookup(A2,[Book2]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,0)
```

But there's more detail on how to do a [vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) in the above link.